# My Laravel scheduler run only once each time I run it and then it stops

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, crontrigger

I've  a Laravel 5.3 on an Azure instance, everything is working cool there except my task scheduler, I'm tryin to run an Artisan command automatically every midnight, when I run the same command from the CLI it works well.
I tried to use this command as in the Laravel Doc:

`* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

it worked out just once, then the process ends and not repeated for the 2nd round.

What should I do to let the scheduler run the task everyday?

P.S: here's my code how do I run the command through the kernel:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('rentalRates:run')->daily();
}
```

Comment: How are you scheduling your command?

Comment: @apokryfos I inserted the line code above in the crontab -e

Comment: Did you add it in the laravel schedule in `Console\Kernel.php`  and if so how? (and if not add it)

Comment: @apokryfos yes sure

Comment: @AhmadAl-Hashlamoun, @apokryfos is asking for you to provide the `Console\Kernel.php` code...

Comment: @apokryfos  I've just added my code above

Comment: @NirajShah thank you

Comment: @AhmadAl-Hashlamoun for multi-line code just indent it with 4 spaces instead of using ticks.

Answer (score 3):

Since your command is scheduled to run daily, it will only run once per day if you use `schedule:run`.

If you wish to run the particular command manually (and more than once in a day), you can use the following from command line:

```
php /path-to-your-project/artisan rentalRates:run
```